# What is the best way to represent a form with hundreds of questions in a model

Tags: oop

I am trying to design an income return tax software.

What is the best way to represent/store a form with hundreds of questions in a model?

[image]

Just for this example, I need at least 6 models (T4, T4A(OAS), T4A(P), T1032, UCCB, T4E) which possibly contain hundreds of fields.

Is it by creating hundred of fields? Storing values in a map? An Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One very generic approach could be XML**

XML allows you to

- nest your data to any degree
- combine values and meta information (attributes and elements)
- describe your data in detail with XSD
- store it externally
- maintain it easily
- even combine it with additional information (look at processing instructions)
- and (last but not least) store the real data in almost the same format as the modell...
- and (laster but even not leaster :-) ) there is XSLT to transform your XML data into any other format (such as HTML for nice presentation)

There is high support for XML in all major languages and database systems.

**Another way could be a typical `parts list` (or `bill of materials/BOM`)**

This tree structure is - typically - implemented as a table with a self-referenced `parentID`. Working with such a table needs a lot of recursion...

It is very highly recommended to store your data type-safe. Either use a character storage format and a type identifier (that means you have to cast all your values here and there), or you use different type-safe side tables via reference.

Further more - if your data is to be filled from lists - you should define a datasource to load a selection list dynamically.

**Conclusio**

What is best for you mainly depends on your needs: How often will the modell change? How many rules are there to guarantee data's integrity? Are you using a RDBMS? Which language/tools are you using?

Answer (score 2):

With a case like this, the monolithic aggregate is probably unavoidable (unless you can deduce common fields). I'm going to exclude RDBMS since the topic seems to focus more on lower-level data structures and a more proprietary-style solution, though that could be a very valid option that can manage all these fields.

In this case, I think it ceases to become so much about formalities as just daily practicalities.

Probably worst from that standpoint in this case is a formal object aggregating fields, like a `class` or `struct` with a boatload of data members. Those tend to be the most awkward and the most unattractive as monoliths, since they tend to have a static nature about them. Depending on the language, declaration/definition/initialization could be separate which means 2-3 lines of code to maintain per field. If you want to read/write these fields from a file, you have to write a separate line of code for each and every field, and maintain and update all that code if new fields added or existing ones removed. If you start approaching anything resembling polymorphic needs in this case, you might have to write a boatload of branching code for each and every field, and that too has to be maintained.

So I'd say hundreds of fields in a static kind of aggregate is, by far, the most unmaintainable.

Arrays and maps are effectively the same thing to me here in a very language-agnostic sense provided that you need those key/value pairs, with only potential differences in where you store the keys and what kind of algorithmic complexity is involved. Whatever you do, probably a key search in this monolith should be logarithmic time or better. 'Maps/associative arrays' in most languages tend to inherently have this quality.

Those can be far more suitable, and you can achieve the kind of runtime flexibility that you like on top of those (like being able to manage these from a file and add the fields on the fly with no pre-existing knowledge). They'll be far more forgiving here.

So if the choice is between a bunch of fields in a class and something resembling a map, I'd suggest going for a map. The dynamic nature of it will be far more forgiving for these kinds of cases and will typically far outweigh the compile-time benefits of, say, checking to make sure a field actually exists and producing a syntax error otherwise. That kind of checking is easy to add back in and more if we just accept that it will occur at runtime.

An exception that might make the field solution more appealing is if you involve reflection and more dynamic techniques to generate an object with the appropriate fields on the fly. Then you get back those dynamic benefits and flexibility at runtime. But that might be more unwieldy to initialize the structure, could involve leaning a lot more heavily on heavy-duty (and possibly very computationally-expensive) introspection and type manipulation and code generation mechanisms, and also end up with more funky code that's hard to maintain.

So I think the safest bet is the map or associative array, and a language that lets you easily add new fields, inspect existing ones, etc. with very fast turnaround. If the language doesn't inherently have that quality, you could look to an external file to dynamically add fields, and just maintain the file.